# C# WPF, how to make a label with a delete button on it?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm trying to make a File Attachment function in my program, i have 2 types of attachments (Personal/Professional documents). Picture below.

[image]

What i want to do now, is make the uploaded files appear in a vertical list (below the label & button in each groupbox) as a label with a delete button, i dont know what this function is called. I would like something like the keywords/tags function (like on stackoverflow, youtube...) Picture below.
[image]

Like:

Drivers License [X]

Passport [X]

Visa [X]

As the user can quickly see what files he have alredy uploaded, and quickly remove a file if he made a mistake.

What i have tried so far, is making a stackpanel divided into 2 columns, text on one side, and buttons on the other side, but i didnt get the result that i wanted. Problem is that i dont even know what this function is called, im sure Theres some tutorial somewhere out there, but its hard to search for something you dont know the name of.

Comment: where do you want to use this control?

Comment: @StepUp Inside my 2 groupboxes.

Comment: @RasmusPaulsen please explain where is your problem? Are you stopped by the ItemsControl or by the Label with Button?

Comment: There are only so many controls to chose from.  No magic search.

Answer (score 2):

Use ListView with the style:

```
 <Style x:Key="ListViewPlate" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                                                ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                                                MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And ListView ItemTemplate - in order to works with the delete button use Command (that would require using a Prism), command would transfer selected item as a context.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewPlateItem">
    <WrapPanel>
        <Border Background="Black" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Goldenrod" BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Goldenrod" BorderThickness="2">
            <Button Command="{Binding ElementName = ListViewElement, Path = DataContext.Command"} CommandParameter={"Binding"}">
               <Button.Background>
                  <ImageBrush ImageSource="yourImage.png" TitleMode="None"/>
               </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </Border>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can made style and ItemTemplate a ResourceDictionary, and then use it

```
 <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewPlateItem}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewPlate}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, i will try to do make that Work! will let you know later if it worked out for me. 

I'm not that experienced yet, I'm only on my second semester, maybe i am biting off more than i can chew.

Comment: try to do that, in case of any problems - write them in comments. I`ll try to help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have some type of View Model with data-binding, this can be quite straight forward.  You can have an `ObservableCollection` of uploaded items.   This could just be a simple class holding an identifyer and display name:

```
public class UploadedFileInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

in View Model:

```
ObservableCollection<UploadedFileInfo> UploadedFiles { get; set; }
```

Now you can bind a `ItemsControl` to this collection eg:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UploadedFiles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteFile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This requires a command in the View Model:

```
public ICommand DeleteFile { get; private set;}
```

In View Model Constructor:

```
DeleteFile = new RelayCommand<int>((fileIdToDelete) => deleteFile(fileIdToDelete))
```

Where `deleteFile(int fileToDelete)` is a function to delete the file and remove it from the `ObservableCollection UploadedFiles`

Note, you will have to find the `RelayCommand` class, there is one on the Microsoft WPF pages, there are also implementations in MVVMLight and other MVVM frameworks that you can use.

**EDIT**
A binding in an `ItemsControl` will look for properties on the objects bound to (that is its `DataContext`)

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteFile}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
```

Should have been

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteFile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" />
```

Which will look for the `ICommand` parameter on the main window's `DataContext`

Answer (score 2):

Here is UserControl that is looking like [image: this]

**Xaml code**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ButtonLikeInSO.SpecialTextPresenterWithButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="150" x:Name="This">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayButtonBackGround" Color="Gainsboro"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedButtonBackground" Color="Tomato"/>
    <Style x:Key="ChangeContentOnMouseOverWithAnimationWhenPressed" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonBackGround}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Delete Uploading"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5" Margin="2">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform></ScaleTransform>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="MyBorder" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="RectangleVisibleOnMouseMove" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource RedButtonBackground}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                        <Path x:Name="ButtonPath"
                              Margin="5"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              StrokeThickness="1.5"
                              StrokeStartLineCap="Square"
                              StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                              Stretch="Uniform"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" Data="M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0">
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnMouseMove" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnMouseMove" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseDown">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="0.8" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="0.8" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseUp">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.8" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.8" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextWithDeleteButton">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro">
            <Grid Background="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Background}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Text}" MaxWidth="150" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=DeleteCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ChangeContentOnMouseOverWithAnimationWhenPressed}"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TextWithDeleteButton}"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class SpecialTextPresenterWithButton : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string),
        typeof (SpecialTextPresenterWithButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeleteCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DeleteCommand",
        typeof (ICommand), typeof (SpecialTextPresenterWithButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public SpecialTextPresenterWithButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(DeleteCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeleteCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Using**

```
    <!--you can use binding to DeleteCommand and Text they are dependancy properties-->
    <buttonLikeInSo:SpecialTextPresenterWithButton Background="Aquamarine" DeleteCommand="{Binding DeleteCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Text="LoooooooooooongFileName"/>
```